# Spring boot graphql - How to use an input array? [Fixed]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, controller, mutation

[FIXED, the answer is below]
I'm new to spring boot and graphql so this question might be dump but I didn't found the answer to my question on internet so I'm asking it here.
How are we supposed to use input arrays for graphql mutations ?
Here is how I tried :

```
// schema.graphqls
type Mutation{
    test(input:TestInput):String
}

input TestInput{
    temp:[Int]
}


// @Controller TestInputController.java
@MutationMapping
public String test(@Argument TestInput input){
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println(input);
    return "test";
}

record TestInput(Integer[] temp){}


// mutation in graphiql
mutation{
  test(input:{
    temp:[5]
    })   
}

// result
Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access properties on null bean instance 'input'
```

Do you have an idea of how I can fix that ? Or any resource that can explain me my problem ?

Thanks in advance

---

For fixing the problem, we should use List as input instead of Integer[]

Comment: Cannot understand from the question which java library you are using for GraphQL implementation. You can refer https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/build-graphql-api-with-spring-boot/ and source code https://github.com/ashishlahoti/spingboot-graphql if that is helpful

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was that I had to use List<> in my java controller for the input and not an array type, I will look at your code, it looks nice